# C# how do you "read" an image programatically?

Tags: c#

I dont have a CS background but have worked extensively with C#. Perhaps I would know this answer with a CS background but I'm hoping to get help from all of the smart folks on this site.

Can someone please provide a C# code snippet on how you can programmatically "read" an image with C#? Assume that I have image that is black and white, like a fingerprint. The background can be white or grayscale and the print itself is black. How can I use C# to distinguish between the portions that are part of the image (i.e. the fingerprint) and the background (i.e. white or grayscale)?

Comment: This is an image-processing question, and doesn't necessarily mean if you had a CS background you'd understand it. Also, "read" really isn't an appropriate term for what you're trying to do. "Reading" usually means from a device, or from a file. You want to "process" the image, or something like that.

Comment: It is called "image recognition"... search for it and depending on your goals either prepare to learn a lot or find library that would work for you or give up and find something that is interesting too but require less theoretical knowledge :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would load the image using the Bitmap class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
```

You can then "read" the colour of each point using the GetPixel method.

```
var color = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
```

As for how you interpret the image, for example to determine which parts are a fingerprint, that could involve all sorts of complex image processing algorithms, which aren't really C# specific.